# Web services response conversion issue

Tags: java, web-services

I am using 'n' number of web services in my systems. I am very well taking care. But, in recent days I am just seeing a strange behaviour while handling response of one my external systems.

Here is my problem,

**When I request one of my downstream system for getting data, i am getting response with one very big xml. During parsing the response in system, the complete JAVA thread itself got struck more than configured time. So for temporary fix, we request downstream system to limit the response.**

But, how this is happening? Irrespective of how big the data, the unmarshlling process should complete right.

So may i know what was the root cause of this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are unmarshalling then the whole XML will be converted to one object graph containing all the objects specified in the XML. So the bigger the XML the bigger the resulting object graph. Of course this takes more memory, perhaps more than your application has to its disposition, which could lead to an OutOfMemoryException.
If the XML received contains some kind of a list of items you can consider handling it item by item. You will read in one item at a time and then process it and dispose of it. You will then need only the amount of memory to fit one item's object graph in memory. But to do this you would have to rewrite your processing code to use a library like [SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html).